# Switch which is connected with SFP don't assign IP addresses in the same subnet

Tags: switch, sfp

In our office, I have connected 2 D-LINK (DGS-1210-52 and DGS-1210-24) switches with SFP cable.

The problem is that the devices that are connected through DGS-1210-24 don't get IP address in the same subnet with the devices that are connected through DGS-1210-52.

I tried and I connected the 2 switches with UTP cable and the above problem is gone.

So, why is this happening when I connect the 2 switches with fibair?

[image]

Comment: Could you post the configuration of your switches?

Comment: Where is your DHCP server?

Comment: I haven't done any special configuration in the switches. The DHCP server is enabled on the router..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well.. `Cown` asked the configuration of the switch and I responded that I haven't done any.. This was the dark point..

In the switch `DGS-1210-24` settings the  `DHCP Auto Configuration` was disabled by default.. The manual of the switch writes that:

> This window allows you to enable the DHCP Auto Configuration feature
>   on the Switch. When enabled, the Switch becomes a DHCP client and gets
>   the configuration file from a TFTP server automatically on next boot
>   up. To accomplish this, the DHCP server must deliver the TFTP server
>   IP address and configuration file name information in the DHCP reply
>   packet. The TFTP server must be up and running and store the necessary
>   configuration file in its base directory when the request is received
>   from the Switch.

I enabled it and all works fine...